# what is the name of the video codec that could dynamic adjust resolution and FPS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I remember that there is video codec could dynamic adjust frame rate and resolution. 
For example, sender side, always send a base profile with QQVGA with 15 FPS, and receiver side always could at least decode QQVGA with 15 FPS. As long as there is more capacity in the bandwidth or CPU process time, sender side could add more details on the pixel of each frame. For example, add more details in the QQVGA, then new frame can be decoded as QVGA or VGA. And insert frames between frames in base profile. The 15 FPS can be 30 FPS etc..
I wonder what is the name of this codec. If I remember it correctly, YouTube uses this codec and Google holds the patent of this video codec.

If someone could remind me what is the name of this codec and more details of this codec. thanks